# Will trends in ORM eventually kill the DBAs?

Tags: database, entity-framework, orm

In our office we have a DB team who does all the database definitions from the ground up. That would include all the tables, indexes, SPs, etc. They also do some policies where certain users can only access certain SPs.

I see switching to Entity Framework or Hybernate is like us developers doing the stuffs that DBAs are doing already. The code first philosophy is practically taking away the job from DBAs and to make matters worst is that the trend with ORMs is moving out of the SP paradigm using adhoc queries.

I must be missing something. What will be the role of the DBAs within the ORM approach?

Comment: was just thinking about this topic and where SQL Server/DBAs will evolve to. Not appropriate for SO though...

Answer (score 3):

Eventually profiling will reveal that to the best performance you need, you will need to optimize at the database level, and this includes hand crafted queries and indexes that require the need of a DBA.

Comment: One problem is that ORMs by default tend to emit queries requesting all columns in a row, often making covering indexes impractical

Comment: Plus, who's to say that databases won't dynamically maintain their own indexes based on the workload?

Comment: I think it will be object databases that will threaten DBAs, however I still don't think they will go anywhere. Someone has to do the mundane database maintenance and controlling tasks.

Comment: object databases? LOL. they've been promising to deliver for 15 years (at least)

Comment: I find it laughable that writing hand crafted queries or indexes would require a DBA.  There are probably plenty of developers that even know more about database performance profiling than your average DBA.  A good DBA is worth their weight in gold, but I've worked plenty of projects that couldn't afford a DBA.